# How to define the following symbol to stock one element in one list?

Tags: symbols, algorithms

I'm looking for one symbol to indicate that a value is stocked in one list. On way would be to use something like `myList.append(myValue)` but it os not very quick to see and to write.

Indeed, I would like to define the following symbols that is a left arrow followed by one square. This symbol will be used in math formulas.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked through the [comprehensive symbols guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) for an appropriate symbol?

Comment: No, indeed I hope that someone has already find this. If I have one idea, I would have ask how to obtain that symbol.

Comment: OK. While I do write algorithms with lists, I never came across a special symbolic way for expressing appending.

Comment: You just write it like I'm doing but maybe some symbolic notations could help for faster reading. This is why I'm looking for something more formal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\boxleft` from `pxfonts` package will do something similar to what you want:

[image]

The package also has these other symbols:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add a square to an arrow, if your fonts don't have the symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\stock}{\gets\mathrel{\mkern-2.4mu\mathop\square}}

\begin{document}
$L\stock a$
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\mathop\square` we vertically shift the square so that it's aligned with the arrow at mid height. With `\mathrel` we ensure no space will be added other than the explicit back up we're doing. The resulting symbol is considered as a relation, as far as spacing is concerned.

Comment: The whole definition should be included in a extra group, or perhaps a `\mathrel`, otherwise the user gets a surprise with `\( L^\stock \)`.

Comment: A couple of braces wouldn't help, as it would change the nature of the symbol; a `\mathrel` wouldn't help either. It wouldn't be the only symbol with this problem and that's one of the reasons why I always teach `x^{...}` even if the exponent consists of one symbol.

Comment: You are right - if want doesn't want the `\mathord` class then one is stuck with have to put braces on the superscript.  I now see that this property shared by standard commands such as `\cong` and `\notin`.  I hadn't noticed it before.